# Injective change of ring theorems

Tags: homological-algebra, injective-module

I am doing the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a ring, $x\in R$ a central non-unit non-zerodivisor. If $A\neq 0$ is an $R/xR$ module with $id_{R/xR}A$ finite, then $$id_R(A)=1+id_{R/xR}A$$ where $id_{R}（id_{R/xR}）$ means injective dimension as a module over $R(R/xR)$

This is Exercise 4.3.3 of Weibel's *Introduction to homological algebra*. I am trying to mimic the proof of the corresponding theorem for projective dimension (theorem 4.3.3 in the book), which uses induction on $n=pd_{R/x}A$. The problem is that I cannot prove the base case, which says that:

> If $A$ is an injective $R/xR$ module, then $id_A=1$.

I can prove that $A$ is not an injective $R$ module, so $id_RA\geq1$, but I cannot prove the other inequality. Can anyone give some hints to me?
Thanks in Advance.